# How to show data from postgresql table without refreshing page (live update)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, razor

Im making a page in razor pages asp.net c# where i want to show the values of the postgresql table, and when there is something new inserted you see the new updated table on the page without refreshing (live). I know that it probably has to do something with the notify and listen functions, but i could not find any good examples on the internet. I am a little stuck. Hope someone can show me a simple way of how to do it.
Here is the c# code:

```
public List<NotificationModel> ShowNotification()
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<NotificationModel> not = new List<NotificationModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select datumnu, bericht FROM notification ORDER BY datumnu DESC OFFSET 1";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            not.Add(new NotificationModel { Datenow = ((DateTime) dr["datumnu"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), Bericht = dr["bericht"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            return not;
        }
```

And here is the html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <p id ="output"></p>
        <div class="col-3 bg-light">
            <h5 class="font-italic text-left">Old Messages</h5>
            <hr>
            @foreach(var n in @Model.ShowNotification())
                    {
                                                
                        <tr>
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="/Images/Reservation.png"/>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => n.Datenow)
                                                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => n.Bericht)
                                                                    
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                    
                                                
                                                
                    }
            <hr>

                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to make ajax calls on mouse drag, first load some x number of records and show it in UI, later whenever user moves down call an ajax call on demand and send page number kind value and fetch to display on  UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serviceURL = '/ControllerName/GetData';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: param = "", //send page number here
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {     
            console.log(data); // append this to your table as applicable
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
</script>



public class ControlllerName : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /AjaxTest/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Getdata(int pagenumber)
    {//fetch here the data based on pagenumber
        return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }   
   }
```